# Java Double error

Tags: java, double

To this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner wg= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your weight on the Earth ");
    double weight = wg.nextDouble();

    double c;
    c=17*weight/100;
    System.out.println("Your weight on the Moon is: " + c);
    wg.close();
}
```

What is the problem ,when I entered double value, it show me this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What double value do you provide ?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely you use invalid double format. As example usage "," instead of "."

```
Enter your weight on the Earth 55,77
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`InputMismatchException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) is thrown by `Scanner` whenever a user types in a value that isn't the same as the value requested. For example, typing "hello" when you call `Scanner#nextInt` in your code.

What's happened here is that you've called `wg.nextDouble()`, but the **user** has typed in something that someScanner doesn't recognize as a double. You should surround `wg.nextDouble()` with a try-catch block so you know when the user types an illegal value.

Answer (score 0):

Get de input as String and try to parse to a number.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner wg= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your weight on the Earth ");
        String input = wg.next();

        try{
            double weight = Double.valueOf(input);
            double c;
            c= weight * 0.17;
            System.out.println("Your weight on the Moon is: " + c);
            wg.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Please insert a valid number! Ex: 10.6 ");
        }

    }
```